# Как выбрать последний элемент в рекурсивной коллекции?

Tags: c#

Сабж.
Есть вот такая иерархия классов.

```C#
     public class Root
    {
        public LimitedTaxonomy LimitedTaxonomy { get; set; }
    }
    
     public class LimitedTaxonomy
    {
        public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
        public int ProductCount { get; set; }
        public int NewProductCount { get; set; }
        public int ParameterId { get; set; }
        public string ValueId { get; set; }
        public string Parameter { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Child
    {
        public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
        public int ProductCount { get; set; }
        public int NewProductCount { get; set; }
        public int ParameterId { get; set; }
        public string ValueId { get; set; }
        public string Parameter { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

На деле все это превращается вот в такое дерево
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как мне получить последний `Child`? Их может быть от 1 до ....

Comment: Я щас наверное бред сморожу, но вдруг, вы случаем не пробовали написать рекурсивную функцию для поиска в рекурсивном дереве?

Comment: Я совсем не понимаю как к этому подойти и как это делать, 18 час кодинга пошел.

Comment: Обычно - рекурсию рассматривают гдет к 4ой пятой главе книжек "xxx для чайников", сразу после функций циклов и переменных. очень советую ознакомится с теорией рекурсивных функций перед полным погружением. https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.11.php

Comment: Рекурсии зло, можно обойтись циклом

Comment: @4per (взгляд функциональщика)

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум - это [очередь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.7.php). В цикле берёте первый элемент очереди и если в нём нет потомков, то сохраняете его, а если потомки есть, то добавляете их в очередь.

Comment: Если есть возможность сделать без рекурсии - нужно так и сделать. В рекурсии должно быть условие выхода из рекурсии - может в этом условии и возвращать текущий элемент?